# Simple way to assign objects based on constraints?

Tags: dart

I plan to tackle this by writing a bunch of `if` statements within `for/while` loops, but sometimes there are wizards who can simplify my logic quite a bit with things like `map`s, so I figured I'd ask first.

- There is a list of objects of class `Person` (structure below).
- There is a `Set<int> myList` of numbers 1 through x that must each have an assigned `Person`.
- Each `Person` has an `int order` (1 through 4) that is used to prioritize who gets assigned first/most often (1 is assigned before 4, it's OK if 4 never gets assigned if not needed)
- Each `Person` has a `int maxInterval` that they can be assigned. So if the `maxInterval` is 3, then that `Person` can be assigned to `myList` values (1 and 4+) but not (1 and 2) or (1 and 3)
- There are hard and soft `int blackout`s and `int whiteout`s. Black means cannot be assigned to that `myList` value, white means should be assigned to that `myList` value. Hard means absolute rule. Soft means priority, but not required.

  ```
   class Person{

     String id;
     String name;
     int maxInterval;       // Maximum frequency to appear (i.e. every maxInterval)
     int order;             // Value 1 through 4
     Set<int> blackoutSoft; // Request to NOT assign
     Set<int> blackoutHard; // Guaranteed NOT assigned
     Set<int> whiteoutSoft; // Request TO assign
     Set<int> whiteoutHard; // Guaranteed TO assign
     Person(this.id, this.name, this.order, this.blackoutSoft, this.blackoutHard, this.whiteoutSoft, this.whiteoutHard);

   }
  ```

Anyone know of a good way to achieve all or some of this? Even general advice/tips would be appreciated prior to me diving in.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Example of two `Person` objects within the `persons` list.

```
List<Person> persons = {
  Person('uid123', 'My Name', 4, 1, {7, 14}, {}, {}, {23}),
  Person('uid124', 'My Other Name', 7, 2, {}, {}, {}, {}),
  ...
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of an Person object where you write the values of each variable?

Comment: @julemand101 Updated with a `persons` list containing 2 examples of `Person` objects.